# Crear proceso en segundo plano PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy armando una aplicación Web con Codeigniter en la cual un apartado debe ejecutar un proceso que lleva mucho tiempo para finalizar, aprox 40 min.

El proceso funciona bien,al ejecutarlo fuera de la aplicación. Sin embargo cuando lo ejecutó dentro, la aplicación se queda esperando a que el proceso termine, y no me permite interactuar con el resto de las opciones. (Aunque cierre la ventana y abra una nueva con la aplicación)

El proceso lo ejecutó así:

1. Hago la llamada a la función vía http de angular.

   $scope.ejecutarProceso = function(){
        $http.post('productos/conteoProductos');
   }

Clase productos

```
Public function conteoProductos(){
  //Está función sólo busca en la base de datos los productos, genera conteos por cada característica y los inserta en una nueva tabla
  $this->producto->insertar conteo();
}
```

También lo he intentado ejecutar fuera del framework como

```
passthru('usr/bin/php '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/app/procesos/conteo.php");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade a la línea de comandos el símbolo `&` para decirle al sistema operativo que lo ejecute en segundo plano. Si obviamente no quieres saber nada del resultado redirígelo todo a null.

En tu caso el comando quedaría tal que así:

```
passthru('usr/bin/php '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/app/procesos/conteo.php >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
```

> NOTA: Esto sólo sirve para sistemas operativos *nix

Comment: Excelente, eso era lo que me hacía falta.